# How to remove old snapshots from /var/openebs on servers?

Tags: storage, snapshot, openebs

What are the steps to remove the old snapshots from the directory `/var/openebs`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [merge](https://github.com/openebs/jiva/pull/113) will be solution